# Separability of the space of bounded uniformly continuous functions

Tags: general-topology, functional-analysis

Let $(X,\rho)$ a metric space. Do the space $U_b(X)$ of uniformly continuous and bounded real-valued functions on $X$ is separable?

It seems that the point is to pass through the Stone-Cech compactification of $X$ denoted by $\beta X$. Then, each  $f\in U_b(X)$
have a unique extension $\tilde f \in C_b(\beta X)$.The latter being a separable space! But,  I am not sure about an homeomorphism between these spaces which would provide the separability of $U_b(X)$ too.

Any hints or references would be welcome,

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is $X$ separable, or compact or something?

Comment: Oh yes, of course X is not compact. It can be separable if needed, but I'm not sure it is necessary. My main concerns is about Polish space so, we can suppose this.

Comment: Generally, the space is not separable. For $X = \mathbb{N}$ with the usual metric, we have $U_b(X) = \ell^\infty(\mathbb{N})$, as an obvious example.

Comment: Passing through the Stone-Cech compactification does not help in general, as the latter is not metrizable in general, and hence $C(\beta X)$ fails to be seperable (note, that for $K$ compact Hausdorff $C(K)$ is separable iff $K$ is metrizable).